# What sort descriptor will keep the order of NSOrderedSet when using FetchRequest in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsorderedset

I have 2 entities in CoreData. `Deck` and `Flashcard`. `Deck` has an ordered to-many relationship with `Flashcard`. This means that `Deck` contains property `flashcards: NSOrderedSet` containing the `Flashcard`s.

In a `DeckView` I try to show all `Flashcard`s from a certain `Deck` in a user-specified order. For that I use `FetchRequest`.

```swift
static func fetchInDeck(deck: Deck) -> NSFetchRequest<Flashcard> {
    let request = Flashcard.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "deck == %@", deck)
    request.sortDescriptors = []
    return request
}
```

The flashcards maintain order until I start adding items, new items get added in seemingly random places, but after restarting the app they go where they should. (e.g. after adding 10 items the order was [3 5 7 9 10 8 6 4 2 1], and after restart [10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]) For adding I used a method generated automatically by Xcode.

```swift
let newFlashcard = Flashcard(context: context)
insertIntoFlashcards(newFlashcard, at: 0)
```

Is there a sort descriptor that will cause those items to stay in order? If not is there another way to maintain the order?

Comment: Off topic but your fetch request function isn't needed, you can use `deck.flashcards` directly

Comment: @JoakimDanielson lol thanks. that works. thought it wouldn't react to changes but i guess i was mistaken